# can't connect to epson network printer

Tags: networking, drivers

I have an Epson nx625 printer/scanner connected to my netgear router with wifi. Ubuntu 14.04 sees the printer but when I install epson drivers it locks up, when I install generic drivers it works but when I try to print a test page it stops at trying to connect and eventually says `can't connect`

Comment: I'm sorry I was confused. my printer is connected by wifi not usb

Comment: yes. same thing